# How to quickly show program help in pager

Tags: shell, zsh

I often find myself appending `--help|less` to commands that I am crafting a command in a shell to explore the CLI of the program I am using. What ways are there to accomplish the same thing with fewer key-presses?

For instance, if I wanted to use the new way of switching branches (I don't, I'm stuck in my ways happily doing `git checkout -b other_branch`) then my history (and thought process) could look like

```
git change other_branch  # Guess what the command should be
git --help|less          # Backtrack to where I am confident I know the command and ask for help
git switch --help|less   # Gradually build up the command from there
git switch other_branch
```

For context:

- I typically want the pager either to be able to search or because I am working in tmux and activating scrolling takes a few additional, and awkward, key-presses.
- I typically use zsh on Ubuntu or Debian.
- I typically use arrow up to iterate on my previous command.

Comment: For starters, `git` is usually configured to invoke `less` for you in this case; `git help` and `git --help` are the exceptions. `git switch --help` should be sufficient; if not, see `git config --help` and search for "pager".

Comment: `zsh` also lets you push a partial command to a stack by hitting `ESC-q`. You type `git switch`, decide you don't know what comes next, and hist `Esc-q` to get a fresh prompt to execute `git switch --help`. Once that exits, the partial command `git switch` is restored to the prompt for additional editing.

Comment: The `Esc-q` shortcut seems nice, I'm sure I will find a use for it. But I do not see how it will reduce the amount of typing I need to do? Also, git was a poor example as it both uses a pager and has a man page, sorry about that.

Comment: If you start with `git switch`, then realize you don't remember the option you need, you can hit Esc-q, run the necessary help command, and when you exit, `git switch` will still be there, so you don't have to retype it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```
# Alt-H: Open `man` page of current command.
unalias run-help
autoload -Uz run-help{,-{git,ip,openssl,p4,sudo,svk,svn}}
```

Then restart your shell.

Now, whenever you're in the middle of typing a command, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> (`^[h`) to immediately open the `man` page for that command. Then, after you quit your pager, Zsh will will automatically restore your command line, so you can finish typing.

Comment: Neat, happy to learn about alt+h, surprised it took this long. Is there a way to make it work with arbitrary programs that implement a `--help` flag? If for instance I try to use it with `pip` then the shell complains that there is _no manual entry for pip_.

Comment: Just add this function to your `$fpath` or `.zshrc` file and `run-help` will automatically pick it up: `run-help-pip() { pip --help | $PAGER }`

Comment: Also neat. Is it possible to make it work with any command without having to enumerate them ahead of time? `pip`, `pip install`, `pip-compile`, `black`, `pytest`, etc (if you are now thinking I must be a python programmer you'd be correct)

Comment: You'd have to write your own `run-help` function for that, which is a bit too much to do in a comment here.  You should probably open a new question for that.

Comment: Thank you for all your kind help. I made a brief attempt at writing a `run-help` function and it works for arbitrary commands but not for sub-commands. Pretty close.

Comment: I was also inspired to research another approach and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349085/text-insertion-bindings-in-zsh) which I adapted to append " --help|less" and run when I press ^h. Not sure if it can be improved to restore the old buffer afterwards but it is good enough.